# Continuously scrolling Gallery?

Tags: android, scroll, android-gallery, custom-scrolling

I have a Gallery object that scrolls from left to right and back again.  However, I would like to make this Gallery circle back on itself, that way when I get to my last View, the very first one is next and I can just keep scrolling.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Blog post: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galleries use an Adapter to back the data that they display.  You can create a custom adapter where `getCount()` returns Integer.MAX_VALUE and `getView()` does a modulos the position with the number of images you have.  This way it always returns the appropriate image for a given position.

Comment: I implemented that like this:  position = position % mImageIds.length;  However, it only scrolls infinitely from left to right.  Would you happen to know how to make it go infinitely both ways?  Thanks very much for your help, by the way.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Do you know how to make it scroll infinitely in both directions, though?  As it is it will only go to the right infinitely.  I should have been more clear in my original question.

Comment: you can use `setSelection(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)` to start in the middle.  note that this isn't really an infinitely repeating list but it should be close enough from a user standpoint.